# Refactoring procedural code into OOP, difficulties with scoping

Tags: php, oop

I am currently refactoring a huge switch that parses a page from procedural code to OOP.

I have some builder-classes that need a few dependencies that have scoping issues at the moment.

This is a snippet of the code before:

```
function parsePage($sLanguageCode) {
    $oTranslator = new translator($sLanguageCode);
    $aTranslations = $oTranslator->translations('page');
    $oBuilderClass = new builder($aTranslations);


    //... queries to get data and set pagedata and get the template file
    $oPageData = $oPage->getData();
    $aTemplateTags = $oTemplate->getTags();    
    foreach($aTemplateTags as $sTag) {

        switch($sTag) {
            case 'php':
                if(is_object($oPageData->getPhp())) {
                    include $oPageData->getPhp()->getData();
                } elseif(is_array($oPageData->getPhp())) {
                    foreach($oPageData->getPhp() as $oElement) {
                        include $oElement->getData();
                    }
                }                   
                break;
            case 'element':
                if(is_object($oPageData->getElements())) {
                    $oBuilderClass->buildElement($oPageData->getElements()->getData());
                } elseif(is_array($oPageData->getElements())) {
                    foreach($oPageData->getElements() as $oElement) {
                        $oBuilderClass->buildElement($oElement);
                    }
                }
                break;       
            //... A lot more cases here, like 20
        }
    }

    //....
}
```

As you can see above, there is a lot of duplicate code present and I need to retreive the data in more functions, thus I wanted to encapsulate the logic inside objects to prevent duplicate code.
This is a snipped of the code in OOP:

```
function parsePage($sLanguageCode) {
    $oTranslator = new translator($sLanguageCode);
    $aTranslations = $oTranslator->translations('page');
    $oBuilderClass = new builder($aTranslations);

    //... queries to get data and set pagedata and get the template file
    $oPageData = $oPage->getData();
    $aTemplateTags = $oTemplate->getTags(); 
    foreach($aTemplateTags as $sTag) {
        $oPageData->outputData($sTag);

    //....   
}
```

The pageData class, containing all the data-objects, looks something like:

```
class pageData {
    protected $aPhpFragments;
    protected $aElementFragments;

    public function outputData($sTag) {
        switch($sTag) {
            case 'php':
                foreach($this->aPhpFragments as $oPhpFragment) {
                    $oPhpFragment->render();
                }
                break;
            case 'element':
                foreach($this->aElementFragments as $oElementFragment) {
                    $oElementFragment->render();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the data classes look like:

```
class phpFragment {
    private $sData;

    function render() {
        return include $oElement->sData;
    }
}

class elementFragment {
    private $sData;

    function render() {
        echo $oBuilderClass->buildElement($this->sData);
    }
}
```

Most of these data objects can render their content without any dependecies, but some need a few builder/data objects. Like the elementFragment class, this needs the $oBuilderClass with the translations set.
I only want to create these dependecy objects once, because some are pretty big and e.g. containing alot of translations. 
The data objects get serialized and stored into the MySQL database.

**Questions:**

1. How can I use the builder-object into my fragment-objects?
2. Some of the objects get stored into the database, so when I use reference variables inside the new objects, these references will get stored too?

Comment: I would always try to avoid storing objects, in their raw form, in a database. Give them a method like `public function storeInDatabase()`, and `public function RetrieveFromDatabase()`, which only stores the essential data of the object, preferably mapping properties to column fields of the database. PHP objects should stay in PHP, and a database should contain decent data you can work with, even without PHP.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I will take it into consideration. This doesn't answer my question however, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: That was the answer to question 2: Don't store raw objects in a database. If there are links between objects you have to make them explicit, with unique identifiers, and store those in the database. I don't quite understand your first question, are you using some kind of framework? Perhaps someone else can answer it?

Comment: Two things you can do

1) Single ton object factory to create instance of oBuilderClass and oElement class, which shall be called inside render function as needed
2) Dependency Injection using constructor, where you shall pass the respective objects in the constructor which can be further used inside render function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency injection pattern would really help your scoping problems. Here is a good article on using the dependency injection pattern in PHP:
http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I kinda figured it out on myself, but this is what I used so, for me, it is the right answer